# Using checkboxes to read and update database

Tags: asp.net

I have thre database feilds which save a single Charecter or null value in the database
I would like to use these three feilds on my form as checkboxes. 
They should be checked if their corresponding database feild are not null and should be unchecked if they are null.again if i want to make changes to those feilds i should be able to do it with a submit button.

I have been acheiving the above functionality by using text boxes instead of check boxes using which users have been entering text which is unnecessary

I have been using sqldatareader to read data into the text feilds as of now

please direct  me towards a similar example or how do i get started

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample of doing this with a DataSet, but the principle is the same (Caveat: first link is to my own blog post):

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/10/12/Bind-CheckBoxList-to-DataSet.aspx

[Pre-Selecting Items in a CheckBoxList Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111634/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050703-1.aspx)